# In angular, add hours to ISO string date format

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and now I want to add 5.30 hours to ISO date string. Eg: 2021-04-28T11:00:00.000Z
How can we do that?

Comment: Please edit the question and include code you've tried and errors you've encountered.

Comment: It would be nice for us to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js library for date related operations.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Answer (score 0):

use moment
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

```
moment().toISOString() // "2021-04-28T10:17:50.058Z"
```